# Windows Forms Elements change default Settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to set the default settings for for exaple a picture box? a 'normal' picturebox backcolor is 'control' can I change to 'transparent' as default ?

thanks in advance :3

Comment: Sure, just derive your own class from PictureBox.  Making it a true default is a bit elaborate, but just setting the BackColor property in the constructor is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Property Panel and change the BackColor to Transparent.

Click on your PictureBox and in the property panel in BackColor chose Web and the first option should be Transparent.

Comment: well i know that, however it wasn't exactly my question. my original question was when I drag 'n drop a picturebox it's by default backcolor 'control' i want it to be default 'transparent' so i don't have to change it all the time